# How do I add the Server Hyper-V Emulator 8.1 to my existing project?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, hyper-v

I have **Windows Server R2 DataCenter w/Hyper-V** running, installed the SDK's for **Windows Phone** development and the **Windows Phone Emulator 8.1 U1** is running.  On my **Windows 8.1** I use **Visual Studio 2013 Community** for my *Universal App* development and its also installed on the server.

As of now I have not made any settings changes on the server, so everything is at its default.  I already had a working *Universal App* project running before deciding to use my server (due to I broke my Windows Phone device the other day) for testing my **Window Phone** app.

Now I have to do all my Windows Phone development on the Server after making modifications and addition to my Windows App on my development machine (**NOTE:** Windows 8.1 doesn't have a VT cpu).

So my question is, is it possible to add the **Windows Emulator 8.1 U1** to my Windows 8.1 project from the Server?  This way I don't to keep going to the Server to test the **Windows Phone** app.

**Updated 4-1-2015:** additional information and better explanation of question.

Thanks!...

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to this remotely hosted emulator from your local machine? Or are you trying to set up team build w/ UI tests on your remote machine?

Comment: Hi eyebraus, thanks for the replay.  I should have explain my situation better so I updated my question.

Comment: Oh so are you asking if it's possible to install the **Windows 8.1 Simulator** on Server R2? This is different from the Phone emulators and should be present on any machine that can do store development.

Comment: No, was wondering if its possible to run the **Emulator** that's on my Server from Visual Studio on my **Window 8.1**, because it doesn't a **VT CPU**.  As of now I have to keep updating the project on the Server to do Phone development and testing?

Comment: Oh okay, that's what I thought you were asking at first. This is not supported as far as I'm aware. Will post an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you'd like to be able to do the following:

- You have a machine X for development, which you can't install emulators on
- You have a server Y w/ Phone emulator running
- You want to deploy your app directly from machine X to server Y

Unfortunately, remote debugging/deployment to an emulator hosted on a different machine is not supported by VS, at least as far as I'm aware. :(

One thing you could try is using [Team Foundation Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to automatically build and deploy your app on your R2 server. You could implement it such that anytime you checked code in, it would be available for ad-hoc testing on your server a few minutes later. This would still mean using Remote Desktop to use the remote emulator, but it would automate the work of getting your changes over to the server. That way you wouldn't have to develop directly on the server.

Comment: Thanks eyebraus, this sounds good!  I appreciate you taking the time to look into this future and I will mark this as answered.  I don't have enough reputations points to give you a "useful answer point", but I hope someone will.  Thanks Again!...